# pandas time differences (delta between rows)

Tags: python, pandas, time, delta

I have a column with timestamps (strings) which look like the following:

```
2017-10-25T09:57:00.319Z
2017-10-25T09:59:00.319Z
2017-10-27T11:03:00.319Z
```

Tbh I do not know the meaning of Z but I guess it is not that important.

How to convert the above strings into correct timestamp **to calculate the difference/delta (e.g. in seconds or minutes)**?

I want to have a column where the deltas between one to anoter timestamp are listed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert the string to datetime format.  Then get the time difference/delta by [`.diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html). Finally, convert the timedelta to seconds by [`.dt.total_seconds()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html), as follows:

(Assuming your column of string is named `Date`):

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['TimeDelta'] = df['Date'].diff().dt.total_seconds()
```

**Result:**

Time delta in seconds:

```
print(df)

                              Date  TimeDelta
0 2017-10-25 09:57:00.319000+00:00        NaN
1 2017-10-25 09:59:00.319000+00:00      120.0
2 2017-10-27 11:03:00.319000+00:00   176640.0
```